# redirect browser in SimpleHTTPServer.py?

Tags: python, scheme, racket

I am partially through implementing the functionality of [SimpleHTTPServer.py](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/SimpleHTTPServer.py) in Scheme. I am having some good fun with HTTP request/response mechanism. While going through the above file, I came across this- " # redirect browser - doing basically what apache does" in the code".

Why is this redirection necessary in such a scenario?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Imagine you serve a page

```
http://mydomain.com/bla
```

that contains

```
<a href="more.html">Read more...</a>
```

On click, the user's browser would retrieve `http://mydomain.com/more.html`. Had you instead served

```
http://mydomain.com/bla/
```

(with the same content), the browser would retrieve `http://mydomain.com/bla/more.html`. To avoid this ambiguity, the redirection appends a slash if the URL points to a directory.

Answer (score 3):

It simplifies things to treat the trailing / as irrelevant when the user does a GET on a directory, so that (say) `http://www.foo.com/bar` and `http://www.foo.com/bar/` have exactly the same effect.  Simplest (though not fastest, see Souders' books;-) is to have the former cause a redirect to the latter.

Comment: ah, that was simple.. I will wait for while if any one got any thing to share. Thanks!